# How could I load i18n strings of array into javascript in a properway

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

I got this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

I tried to escaped ruby variable into javascript var, but it failed.

How could I do that in haml file thanks~

## i18n yaml file

```
weekdays:
  - 日
  - 一
  - 二
  - 三
  - 四
  - 五
  - 六
```

## haml

```
 :javascript
    var daysOfWeekValue = #{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.weekdays').to_json} ;
```

## html

```
 var daysOfWeekValue = [\"日\",\"一\",\"二\",\"三\",\"四\",\"五\",\"六\"] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want

```
var daysOfWeekValue = ["日","一"] ;
```

(shortend, the difference is the escaping (`\"` vs `"`). I think you double escape with the `.to_json`and `escape_javascript` methods. I am not really sure what is the rails way; I came about a situation lately (python, non-rails) where I happily and successfully used the `.to_json` approach. Probably reading up the docs of `escape_javascript` and experiment with either of the two functions will lead you to the **proper way(tm)**. Feel free to edit my answer to point out the "better" solution in a small section.